# Access Angular component property/ function inside callback functions of anime.js

Tags: javascript, angular, callback, anime.js

I am new to Js and I am trying to create a simple app where I need to call an Angular component function after the animation completes. For animation, I am using anime.js and  I am using Angular framework to create this app.

I have added the animation code inside the ngAfterViewInit function and I want to call `showOptions()` function of Angular component inside the **complete** callback of anime.js.
But inside **complete** callback I am not able to access this component function. I tried to define the component object **comp** and then tried to use this object inside callback function to call the **showOptions** function but it's giving error

> Cannot read property 'showOptions' of undefined

Also calling the showOptions function directly did not work.

My code:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.an-2');
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
    anime.timeline({loop: false})
      .add({
        targets: '.an-2 .letter',
        opacity: [0,1],
        easing: "easeInOutQuad",
        duration: 2250,
        comp: this,
        delay: (el, i) => 150 * (i+1),
        complete: function (anim) {
          console.log('Completed' + anim);
          this.comp.showOptions();
        }
      });
  }

showOptions(){
   console.log('Show options called.');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the normal callback to arrow function like below :-

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.an-2');
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
    anime.timeline({loop: false})
      .add({
        targets: '.an-2 .letter',
        opacity: [0,1],
        easing: "easeInOutQuad",
        duration: 2250,
        comp: this,
        delay: (el, i) => 150 * (i+1),
        complete:(anim) => {
          console.log('Completed' + anim);
          this.comp.showOptions();
        }
      });
  }

showOptions(){
   console.log('Show options called.');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Askash It worked, without using "this.comp" because this now represents to component object so I used "this.showOptions()" directly. 
But now I am interested to know how it worked and If I want to refer to someproperty from anime like "duration" for example, how that can be done.

Comment: normal function and arrow functions have different lexical scope. thats why it worked.